# Is there a need for Low Resolution Images

Tags: sdk, coronasdk

I am using Corona sdks for app development, my app is built for iPad (1536*2048 pixels), but I would like it to also work on iPhone. Do i need to make lower resolution images for the iPhone in order for the app to work well on the smaller screen of those devices. If so, what code can i use to achieve that.

Comment: you should make your app suitable for all devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't hurt to make them lower resolution. It would probably make it run faster as it doesn't have to load as much nor use resources in the mobile and make it run slower.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make them. You can go without them and your images will be downscaled. it will make game slowe in old devices like 4s.